# How to get the minimum ancestor of a node in a binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

Let T be the tree

```
           12
       6        3
   13
1     14
```

For the node (1), the minimum ancestor would be 6. For node (3), the minimum ancestor would be 12. I am trying to write a recursive solution that returns the minimum ancestor of a node.

```
int MinParent(struct Node *root, struct Node *target) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    if (root->data == target->data) {
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    int res = root->data;

    if ((MinParent(root->left, target) == INT_MAX) || (MinParent(root->right, target) == INT_MAX)) {
        int res = min(??);

        return ??;
    }

    return res;
}
```

I am able to get to each ancestor node for a given target node, but I can't figure out how to get the minimum for these nodes.

Comment: I would use a depth-first search. That way, when you find the desired node, the stack contains all of the ancestors of that node.

Comment: Do children have pointers to their parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you traverse the tree, keep track of the minimum you've found on that path. This can easily be done by adding a third argument, the minimum found so far.

If you find the target, return the minimum.

If you reach a leaf, return `INTMAX`.

```
int MinParent_(struct Node *node, int target, int min) {
   if (node == NULL)
      return INTMAX;

   if (node->data == target)
      return min;

   if (node->data < min)
      min = node->data;

   int rv = MinParent_(node->left, target, min);
   if (rv != INTMAX)
      return rv;

   return MinParent_(node->right, target, min);
}

int MinParent(struct Node *root, int target) {
   return MinParent_(root, target, INTMAX);
}
```

This uses a sentinel value. This means that the data can't contain `INTMAX`. We could use a pointer to node with the minimum value instead of the minimum value itself to remove that restriction.

```
struct Node *MinParent_(struct Node *node, int target, struct Node *min_node) {
   if (node == NULL)
      return NULL;

   if (node->data == target)
      return min_node;

   if (!min_node || node->data < min_node->data)
      min_node = node;

   struct Node *rv = MinParent_(node->left, target, min_node);
   if (rv)
      return rv;

   return MinParent_(node->right, target, min_node);
}

struct Node *MinParent(struct Node *root, int target) {
   return MinParent_(root, target, NULL);
}
```

Comment: `If you reach a leaf, return INTMAX` good plan. `if (node == NULL)
      return min;` dubious implementation.

Comment: @graybeard, Fixed. (This is just one of the reasons why we expect question to include a minimum, runnable demonstration of the problem. Without that, we can't correctly test.)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by performing a BFSs (or DFSs, doesn't really matter), and each node should carry the minimum value of all ancestors. For example:

```
               3(3)
           5(3)    6(3)
        2(3)
     1(2)  4(2)
```

In order to store the answers for all nodes, let's create a map `minimumAncestor`.

Given a node `u`, the algorithm to evaluate all the minimum ancestors of all the nodes in the subtrees rooted in `u` is:

```
DFS(u, minimumInAncestors){
    minimumAncestor[u] = minimumInAncestors;
    foreach child v of u:
        DFS(v, min(u, minimumInAncestors));
}
```

To fill the map, you call `DFS(root, root)`.

By doing this, the map `minimumAncestor[u]` should return the right minimum ancestor of any node `u` by the end of the DFSs (with exception of the root, whose minimum ancestor is itself).

Comment: It should be noted that this approach adds O(N) memory cost on top of the O(N) traversal cost to map the entire tree - but that may be amortized, yet we don't know how many lookups there are compared to N. And at that point one might as well store parent pointers at the same O(N) memory cost, but the traversal from `target` to `root` becomes O(log N). Given the flexibility this affords, it may be a more general approach. The access and modification patterns matter now since cache stalls are in the real picture. In a trivial implementation, `log N` extra stalls would be incurred per lookup.